# Using php as external javascript with CakePHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp, cordova

PHP files can be used as external javascript files. Basically make a php file output valid javascript and use that php file as your javascript file: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp.shtml . Can this be done with cakephp since we don't specify php files in the browser but rather a directory based on controllers and their actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, as long as you output valid JS, id does not matter what the URL looks like and what is behind that URL.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but anyway, this is how I did it.
When linking to external javascript file, don't forget to set inline to false like the one shown below:

```
$this->Html->script('scriptname', array('inline' => false));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you link a javascript file with

```
$this->Html->script('scriptname');
```

all that happens is that a tag is created in the HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/webroot/js/scriptname.js"></script>
```

So, you can link whatever you'd like.

Comment: sorry, i should have been more clear and through about my question. I want a view that only has javascript in it, then in a totally different application somewhere else, on a different server to access the that view file as if it was javascript file. did i make any sense?

Comment: @amirrustam If I understand you correctly, what you need is to create a layout that has nothing in it. This way, the javascript won't be surrounded by your usual HTML template. You can set the layout in the controller's action method.

Comment: and then how would i reference (http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp.shtml) that view (the one with the empty layout) as a javascript file in a different application (as in NOT an php application) on different server somewhere else.

Comment: @amirrustam You would just use the URL in the same way that you would use any other CakePHP url: http://yourdomain.com/controller/action. The only thing to make sure of is that you set the Content-type to 'text/plain' in PHP.

Comment: In cakephp if we have a controller named "foos" and in that controller we have an action named "bar" then i can go that by http://site.com/foos/bar. Now I will set the layout for the "bar" action to be empty (just like you said) and then output just javascript. so essentially the view for the "bar" action is a javascript file. So i want to use that outputted javascript code as javascript file and reference it from another non-php application somewhere else.

Comment: I can't just do <script type="text/javascript" src="http://site.com/foos/bar"></script> (http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp.shtml) because that's not how cakephp works. So what I can do? Are there any other methods? Thank you I really appreciate the help